# Converting excel file names to pandas data frame columns

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have around 1500 excel files which are formatted in a similar way. I need to clean and prepare the data to be ingested into a visualisation tool. Most of the cleaning is easy and I've taken care of that. I'm working on one file right now and I'll loop through all the files once this is done.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~/')
path_to_file = userhome + 'Downloads/arunachal-pradesh/'
file_name = 'Maker Month Wise Data  of WEST KAMENG - AR4 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file + file_name)
df.columns = df.iloc[2]
df = df.drop(df.index[0:3])
df = df.iloc[:,1:14]
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "Maker"}, inplace = True)
df.head(30)
```

This outputs a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

Now my challenge is that I need to use the filename to extract 3 datapoint - the RTO, the state, and the year and add them as three separate columns in the data frame. This is a short sample of the files I have:

```
Maker Month Wise Data  of WEST KAMENG - AR4 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of UPPER SIANG - AR14 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of TIRAP - AR13 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of CHANGLANG - AR12 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of UPPER SUBANSIRI - AR7 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of KURUNG KUMEY - AR15 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of ITANAGAR CAPITAL COMPLEX - AR1 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of TAWANG - AR3 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of LOWER DIBANG VALLEY - AR16 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of LOWER SUBANSIRI - AR6 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of KAMLE - AR23 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of YUPIA - AR2 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of EAST SIANG - AR9 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of EAST KAMENG - AR5 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of LOHIT - AR11 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of NAMSAI - AR20 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of SHI-YOMI - AR26 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
Maker Month Wise Data  of WEST SIANG - AR8 , Arunachal Pradesh (2020).xlsx
```

As you can see, they are formatted similarly. The RTO is everything that comes between 'of' and the comma. So, for the first file, the RTO will be `WEST KAMENG - AR4`. The state for these files is `Arunachal Pradesh` but it will change in the complete list of files. The year is `2020`.

I'm been trying to use regex101 to capture these parameters but I'm not too good with regex and haven't been able to figure out the right syntax for it.

Any help in getting this done will be appreciated!

Comment: You say "I'm been trying to use regex101 to capture these parameters", please show the pattern you tried and explain what is wrong with the results.

Comment: For example, I'm trying to isolate the RTO right now with `rto = re.search('\s\sof\s(.*)\s\,', filename)` and I'm getting `<re.Match object; span=(21, 44), match='  of CHANGLANG - AR12 ,'>` as the output. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If you need the string value,  use `print(rto.group())` or `print(rto.group(1))`

Comment: Your regex [looks quite fine](https://regex101.com/r/Q2kVTY/1). Try `df[['RTO','State','Year']] = df['Maker'].str.extract(r'\s+of\s(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\((\d{4})\)', expand=True)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFlvWq/2).

Comment: That solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df[['RTO','State','Year']] = df['Maker'].str.extract(r'\s+of\s(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\((\d{4})\)', expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFlvWq/2). *Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `of` - a word `of`
- `\s+` one or more whitspaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d{4})` - Group 3: four digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Wow that's so concise! I wrote that same code across 6 lines lol. Thank you for sharing this :)